# Between Query on Google Fire Store DB Timestamp filed

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I have Firestore Db Collection and Has more than 100K+ documents in it now I want to fetch documents that are created in the last 1 day

I have the event_time field in all the documents with timestamp datatype. I am using python to connect and query the fire store DB data

I have tried to fetch data using the below query

```
dbconnection = firestore.Client(project="proj_demo")
collectionref = dbconnection.collection(u,'collection_name')

from_date = date.today()
to_date = from_date - timedelta(1)
res = collectionref.where('event_time','>=' to_date).where('event_time','<=',from_date)
```

My DB Structure has below Field and datatypes

```
name: string
message : string
event_time : timestamp
```

The question is how can I get data that are created in the last 1 day

[image: Firestore DB Structure]

Comment: And what's the question? Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo  I Have updated the details

Comment: Please check again my frost comment. We need a **screenshot**.

Comment: Added the screenshot

Comment: Have you tried to use `collectionref = dbconnection.collection(u,'messages')`?

Comment: it will work but there will be lots of documents inside the message collection,what i want to do it get those documents that are created in last one day

Comment: If you're using `res = dbconnection.collection(u,'messages').where('event_time','>=' to_date).where('event_time','<=',from_date)`, does it work?

Comment: No it is not working, it shows an error invalid type <class datetime.date>

Comment: Are `from_date` and `to_date` Firestore timestamps?

Comment: What I Understood is I am getting the invalid type error because the date format of the from_date and to_date ate different from the firestore DB Timestamp Field

Comment: If we can somehow manage to convert the from and to dates to the firestore DBs timestamp then the query will work

Comment: Yes, this is what you should do. Give it a try and tell me if it works.